# operator "+=" overload for matrices in python

Tags: python, math, matrix, overloading

**Problem:**
generally speaking: it is about reloading matrix operators, i.e. so that they perform algebraic operations on matrices.

How can I implement the algebraic operation of addition on matrices, i.e. call **add** the right way.

In this case, I would like to overreload the **+=** operator, but I have no idea how to do it.

**UPDATED**

```
  class MyMatrix:
       height = 0
       width = 0
       data = tuple()
    
       def __init__(self, data):
           self.height = len(data)
           self.width = len(data[0])
           self.data = data
    
       def __getitem__(self, item):
           return self.data.__getitem__(item)
    
       def __add__(mat1, mat2):
           if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
               print("The matrices are not the same size!")
               return
    
           rows = []
           for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
               row = []
               for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
                   row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])
    
               rows.append(tuple(row))
           return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))
    
    // in this method I would like to overload the operator +=
   def __iadd__(self, other):
    if self.height != other.height or self.width != other.width:
        print("The matrices are not the same size!")
        return

    rows = []
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
        row = []
        for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
            row.append(self[i][j] + other[i][j])

        rows.append(tuple(row))
```

Comment: Implement it similarly to the way you implemented `add`

Comment: Except that it modifies `self` instead of returning a new Matrix.

Comment: What is `self.number`? There's no `number` attribute in `Matrix`.

Comment: `add` should be named `__add__` so it's used for the `+` operator.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your answer, can you have a look at the updated code I added, this is how it should look?

Comment: The `__iadd__` method needs to be indented inside the class.

Comment: You should raise an exception when the matrix sizes don't match, not just print a message and return.

Comment: You don't use `row.append()` in `__iadd__`, you just assign to the element: `self[i][j] += other[i][j]`

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by  `__iadd__` method needs to be indented inside the class?

Comment: You need to indent `def __iadd__` so it's at the same level as all the other methods. You're defining it as a regular function, not a method.